# Node Function not returning JSON object

Tags: json, node.js, express

This is my Library function file named verifyToken.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const CognitoExpress = require("cognito-express");

//Initializing CognitoExpress constructor
const cognitoExpress = new CognitoExpress({
    cognitoUserPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID, // User Pool id (created via Console->Cognito Manage User Pool)
    region: process.env.REGION, //User Pool Region
    tokenUse: "id", //Possible Values: access | id
    tokenExpiration: 3600000 //Up to default expiration of 1 hour (3600000 ms)
});

//Our middleware that authenticates all APIs under our 'authenticatedRoute' Router
module.exports = function(){
    this.verifyToken=(function(token, req, res) {

        //I'm passing in the id token in header under key Token
        let TokenFromClient = token;

        //Fail if token not present in header. 
        if (!TokenFromClient) return "Token missing from header";

        cognitoExpress.validate(TokenFromClient, function(err, response) {

            //If API is not authenticated, Return 401 with error message. 
            if (err) {
                return res.send({success:false, msg:"Token Authenication Error", Error:err});
            }

            //Else API has been authenticated. Proceed.
            return res.send({success:true, msg:"Token Authenication result", result: response});
        });
    });
}
```

I am calling this function from controller

```
var verify_tokenController = {};

//Verify AWS token recieved through client header by calling verifyToken Library function
verify_tokenController.verify = function(req, res) {

    //Import verifyToken Library function
    require('../library/verifyToken')();

    var auth = verifyToken(req.header('Token'), req, res);
    console.log(auth);
};

module.exports = verify_tokenController;
```

But I am always receiving undefined at console. How to return err or response back to the calling controller. Both of the return variable are JSON object type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is becuase `cognitoExpress.validate` is an `async` operation. it will run and the callback of this function will run. But by the time this all happens. Your following line

`console.log(auth);` gets hit already and you see undefined becuase you are actually not returning anything from `verifyToken` method at that time.

This how javascript and async operations work.

You can either use the callback approach but that's not what I would recommend. So I'm modifying your code with `promises` and see if it works for you.

Your **verifyToken.js** should look as follow:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const CognitoExpress = require("cognito-express");

//Initializing CognitoExpress constructor
const cognitoExpress = new CognitoExpress({
    cognitoUserPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID, // User Pool id (created via Console->Cognito Manage User Pool)
    region: process.env.REGION, //User Pool Region
    tokenUse: "id", //Possible Values: access | id
    tokenExpiration: 3600000 //Up to default expiration of 1 hour (3600000 ms)
});

//Our middleware that authenticates all APIs under our 'authenticatedRoute' Router
module.exports = function(){
    this.verifyToken=(function(token, req, res) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          //I'm passing in the id token in header under key Token
          let TokenFromClient = token;

          //Fail if token not present in header. 
          if (!TokenFromClient) return "Token missing from header";

          cognitoExpress.validate(TokenFromClient, function(err, response) {

              //If API is not authenticated, Return 401 with error message. 
              if (err)  {
                reject(err);
              } else {
                //Else API has been authenticated. Proceed.
                resolve(response);
              }                            

          });
        });            
    });
}
```

Your controller should look like as follow:

```
var verify_tokenController = {};

//Verify AWS token recieved through client header by calling verifyToken Library function
verify_tokenController.verify = function(req, res) {

    //Import verifyToken Library function
    require('../library/verifyToken')();

    verifyToken(req.header('Token'), req, res)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(resposne, 'response')
        res.send({success:true, msg:"Token Authenication result", result: response});    
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        res.send({success:false, msg:"Token Authenication Error", Error:err});
      });    
};

module.exports = verify_tokenController;
```

Try the above solution.

Comment: Glad to know that.